# CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS vs SHOW TABLES LIKE

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, which is a better practice? Always use "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS", or check first the existence of the table using "SHOW TABLES LIKE" before making the table?

I have to regularly save a page where the table for it may or may not be there (sometimes, it is deliberately deleted when not in use). Previously, I used to do "SHOW TABLES LIKE" to check if that table exists before I insert new entries. But I changed it to "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS". Either way, I just do a "INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE" to add new or update existing data.

I don't know how to benchmark this, which is why I am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performance isn't critical with these operations.

The key aspect is race conditions. If you use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` you know it will happen or it won't. If two threads happen to be doing this statement one will succeed and the other won't be negatively affected.

If a `SHOW TABLE LIKE` was used in both threads, both could detect the table didn't exist, and upon trying to create the table, one would fail.

So use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` to mitigate race conditions. Also in general is better to use a database provided feature than roll your own.

Comment: I never thought about the threads before. Thank you very much.

Comment: With a database, its important to always think about threads/process (and by implication transactions) :-)

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` is option provided by MySQL and good to use. If table will not exist this statement will create else will skip.

other end, if you first check table existence by `show table like` then either skip or create as per result of condition/check. Ultimately you are increasing one step or runtime of you script or program for same functionality which you can achieve in single step.